# Mysterious "unable to resolve host" in dead.letter

Tags: debian, cron, clock

In the `~` directory of the `root` user on my debian wheezy server regularly appears file named `dead.letter` with (currently) the following content:

```
orion : Jul 25 10:17:31 : root : unable to resolve host orion

orion : Jul 26 02:17:18 : root : unable to resolve host orion

orion : Jul 26 21:17:19 : root : unable to resolve host orion
```

`orion` is the hostname of the server (and can normally be resolved since I have various services/programs using this hostname without problems). After some searching I figured that there is a `cron` job running hourly, i.e.

```
17 * * * *  root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

which could explain why those errors only appear 17 minutes after the full hour. The only script in `/etc/cron.hourly` is `fake-hwclock` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Simple cron script - save the current clock periodically in case of
# a power failure or other crash

if (command -v fake-hwclock >/dev/null 2>&1) ; then   
   fake-hwclock save
fi
```

Can this produce those mysterious `dead.letter`? And why seems `fake-hwclock save` try to resolve the hostname?

---

**Edit:** Some more information.

Input of `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: `/etc/hosts` is a starter.

Comment: See edited post. What do I have to look for in `/etc/hosts`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the following line in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

to

```
127.0.0.1       localhost  orion
```

Your [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) was unable to resolve the domain name of your machine.

Comment: I think I have to wait some time to ensure this is the correct answer. But it does make sense to me. Will eventually later mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Some context/explanation would be helpful. Why do these messages appear in dead.letter rather than some log, for example?

Comment: @FaheemMitha see the answer below. Jodkas answer solved the problem for me, but Gerhards answer explains the "why" more detailed.

Answer (score 5):

Jodka Lemon's answer is correct:

- cron executes its job, and sends a result mail to "root@orion" (via "mail" or similar)
- the MTA cannot resolve host orion, since the hostname is not listed in `/etc/hosts` and not resolvable via dns.
- so the mailer writes the dead letter information

You will find the destination address of crons mail output in the crontab file which holds the `/etc/cron.hourly` entry. This sould be `/etc/crontab`, I think...

Have Fun ...
Gerhard